# Visual Studio Unit test ShimsContext messing with Garbage Collector

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, shim

Here is an interesting question: Why does the garbage collection not work for the simple unit test initialization example below? At least for me running VS2013 .NET 4.5 I eventually run out of memory and get a out of memory exception.

The shimmed method is needed, without that the garbage collector works just fine also inside the ShimsContext.

This is boiled down from one of my tests where a large xml file was parsed with several million temporary object creations, eventually leaving me without any memory.

Class under test

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MemoryTester
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        static void MethodToFake()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the original method");
        }
    }

    public class OutsideClass
    {
        public OutsideClass()
        {
        }

        ~OutsideClass()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Unit test class

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MemoryTests
    {
        protected IDisposable Context;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitTest()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                MemoryTester.Fakes.ShimProgram.MethodToFake = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is the shimmed method");
                };

                while (true)
                {
                    //This will never be garbage collected, why?
                    MemoryTester.OutsideClass nc = new MemoryTester.OutsideClass();
                }
            }

            while (true)
            {
                //Outside of ShimsContext, we will garbage collect just fine
                MemoryTester.OutsideClass nc = new MemoryTester.OutsideClass();
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AttributeSerializerMemoryTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }

        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Sorry no, I had to leave it hanging.